# Format number as currency

Tags: php, mysql

I am (learning) using PHP to select column data from MySQL into an array using this, `CONCAT('$',FORMAT(price, '5')) as price` and it outputs  $1,751.60000 or $10.00230 or $7.23000 which is great.

However, I would like to remove the trailing zeros but still be able to have a **minimum of two decimal places**

$1,751.60000 = $1,751.60

$10.00230 = $10.0023

$7.23000 = $7.23

I have read a number of similar post regarding number to currency conversion but none doesn't seem to solve my problem as they remove all the trailing zeros.

Comment: do you want this problem to be solved using SQL only or with PHP?

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem. 1.23456 will get rounded to 1.23, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

We will implement this in two way.(Mysql, PHP).

MYSQL:

`FORMAT('price', 2 )` This is mysql function. It takes first parameter as value & second parameter is the number of decimal places.

Syntax:

```
FORMAT( value, Decimal );
```

Example:

```
FORMAT('1751.60000', 2 ) => 1751.60 // Output
FORMAT('1751.60000', 3 ) => 1751.600 // Output
```

PHP:

In PHP we have number_format() function. This is working same as MYSQL.

Syntax:

```
number_format( value, Decimal );
```

Example:

```
number_format('1751.60000', 2 ) => 1751.60 // Output
number_format('1751.60000', 3 ) => 1751.600 // Output
```

The Best way is to implement at MYSQL.

**Note: These both function round up the values.**

Answer (score -1):

I will post this code in PHP since it is easier for me.

```
$price = $row['price']; // the original price
if (number_format($price, 2) == $price) {
    echo '$'.number_format($price, 2);
} else {
    echo '$'.rtrim(number_format($price, 5),'0');
}
```

`rtrim` will remove any trailing character specified. In this case, remove trailing zeros.

Note : I only put this code `number_format($price, 5)` because of the sample of the question. If you wish to keep all decimal number minus trailing zeros, just using `$price` is enough.

Comment: This will not work as $number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given.

Comment: why my code isn't working? i test it and the result is as expected

Comment: what did you use for $row['price'] ?

Comment: that value is the original value in database.

Comment: if $row['price'] is with "$" this code won't work as number_format() expects float.

Comment: assuming that $row['price'] doesn't contain '$'. typically, '$' doesn't get stored in database

Comment: but user3408056 has CONCAT('$',FORMAT(price, '5')) as price. Which means the query outputs the value with a $ in it,.. However nice try.

Comment: if $ is in database, OP didn't need to CONCAT.